# unable to bind the object from component controller to view in angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a scenario where i need to bind the object from component controller to view which is the response coming from service.

when I am binding that object in html it is binding as empty object which I initialized. But after getting the response it is not updating.

Script:

```
  (function() {
        app.component('tabComponent', {
            bindings: {
                toggle: '<',
                oUserDetails: '<'
            },
            templateUrl: 'components/tabComponent/tabComponent.html',
            controller: tabComponentCtrl
        })

        function tabComponentCtrl(mainService) {
            this.emailPattern = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
            this.phNumberPattern = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/;
            this.namePattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]{1,15}$/;
            this.aEmployeeTypes = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "xyz", "abc", "lmn"];
            this.toggle = true;
            this.oUserDetails = {};
            /* for getting json data*/
            mainService.fnGerUserDetails().then(function(response) {
                this.oUserDetails = response;
                console.log(this.oUserDetails); //response  
          }, function(response) {
                alert('error')
            });
            console.log(this.oUserDetails); //{}
            /*  for updating data to read only form*/
            this.fnSendData = function() {
                this.toggle = true;
            };
        }
    })();
```

Html:

```
    <md-content class="tabs-color">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
        <!-- for first tab -->
        <md-tab label="Tab1">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <img src="{{$ctrl.oUserDetails.img}}" height="200px" width="200px">
                <div layout="column">
                    <form name="userForm" data-ng-submit="$ctrl.fnSendData()">
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.name" ng-pattern="$ctrl.namePattern" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle" required>
                            <div ng-messages="userForm.userName.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">UserName is required.</div>
                                <div ng-message="pattern">Must be maximum 15 characters only</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.email" ng-pattern="$ctrl.emailPattern" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle" required>
                            <div ng-messages="userForm.userEmail.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Email is required.</div>
                                <div ng-message="pattern">Email Is Invalid</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="phNumber" ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.phoneNumber" ng-pattern="$ctrl.phNumberPattern" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle" required>
                            <div ng-messages="userForm.phNumber.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Phone Number is required</div>
                                <div ng-message="pattern">Must be a valid 10 digit phone number</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                            <label>Location:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.location" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle" ng-pattern="$ctrl.namePattern">
                        </md-input-container>
                        <label class="label">Employee Type:</label>
                        <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.employmentType" class="md-no-underline" ng-disabled="$ctrl.toggle" md-selected-text="$ctrl.fnGetSelectedText()">
                            <md-optgroup label="$ctrl.aEmployeeTypes">
                                <md-option data-ng-repeat="type in $ctrl.aEmployeeTypes" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</md-option>
                            </md-optgroup>
                        </md-select>{{text}}
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="$ctrl.oToggle.showOrg">
                            <label>Organization:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="organization" ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.organization" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle" required>
                            <div ng-messages="userForm.organization.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Organization is required</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="$ctrl.oToggle.showExp">
                            <label>Experiance:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="location" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle" ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.yearsOfExperiance" required>
                            <div ng-messages="userForm.location.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Location is required</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-if="$ctrl.oToggle.showOther">
                            <label>Others:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="others" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle" ng-model="$ctrl.oUserDetails.employmentType" required>
                            <div ng-messages="userForm.others.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Others is required</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-button type="submit" class="md-primary" aria-label="Save Data" ng-readonly="$ctrl.toggle">Send</md-button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

json:

```
  {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "user details",
    "devMsg": "token expired.",
    "data": {
        "img": "https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/user-image-with-black-background_318-34564.png",
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "employmentType": "option2",
        "phoneNumber": "9876543210",
        "location": "Hyderbad",
        "yearsOfExperiance": 5,
        "organization": "abc"
    }
}
```

Here `$ctrl.oUserDetails` is binding as `{}` instead of that response.

Comment: are you getting actual response in console.log(this.oUserDetails);

Comment: I edited the question please check  it

Comment: I'm not using angular currently but used it before. As far as I remember you have to assign your stuff to the $scope object to be able to use it in the binding. I can't see anything like that in you code. Can it be the problem?

Comment: I am using angular 1.5 it has a new feature called component.Will it accept $scope?

Comment: please show the code where you are binding or creating alias for controller in your view, may be you are using wrong alias

Comment: why add the angular2 tag when your question **specifically** says angular 1.5?  They aren't the same, or even close enough for those who are versed in only 2.x to be able to help anyone with a 1.x app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the issue is because of using 'this' inside callback function. 
Here:

```
mainService.fnGerUserDetails().then(function(response) {
                this.oUserDetails = response;// here 'this' is callback function
                console.log(this.oUserDetails); //response  
          }
```

**So, this (aka "the context") is a special keyword inside each function and its value only depends on how the function was called, not how/when/where it was defined. It is not affected by lexical scope, like other variables.**

Try this.

```
function tabComponentCtrl(mainService) {
             var that = this;
            this.emailPattern = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
            this.phNumberPattern = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/;
            this.namePattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]{1,15}$/;
            this.aEmployeeTypes = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "xyz", "abc", "lmn"];
            this.toggle = true;
            that.oUserDetails = {};
            /* for getting json data*/
            mainService.fnGerUserDetails().then(function(response) {
            that.oUserDetails = response; // assigning response to new variable.

          }, function(response) {
                alert('error')
            });

            console.log(that.oUserDetails); //{}
            /*  for updating data to read only form*/
            this.fnSendData = function() {
                this.toggle = true;
            };
        }
```

Edit:
Using ES6 syntax:

```
mainService.fnGerUserDetails().then((response)=> {
                this.oUserDetails = response;
                console.log(this.oUserDetails); //response  
          }
```

Comment: Solution 1 is pointless. Why don't you do something similar to solution 2?

Comment: @swathianupuram can you check now with updated answer.

Comment: But I need to know what was the difference in those two.

Comment: i too need to know . @ Ved  @ swathi anupuram.

Comment: The reason is if you use "this" inside callback function. e.x: mainService.fnGerUserDetails().then(function(response) {
                this.oUserDetails = response;// here 'this' is callback function
          }, than "this"  is reference to that callback function.

Comment: @IsettyRavitejakumar  Please  refer to edited answer.